# In which case to use action store_false in python argparse?

Tags: python, argparse

This question is about the very useful argparse Python library.

We know the basic usage:

```
import argparse
parser =  argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--useOptionA",help="activate the useOptionA option", action="store_true")
args=parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

So logically, if we do:

```
python program.py
Namespace(useOptionA=False)

python program.py --useOptionA
Namespace(useOptionA=True)
```

It makes sense, right?

My question is, in which cases (or how) can we use the `action="store_false"` option?

I tried

```
import argparse
parser =  argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--noOptionB",help="do not usethe useOptionB option", action="store_false")
args=parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

but then I get

```
python program.py
Namespace(noOptionB=True)

python program.py --noOptionB
Namespace(noOptionB=False)
```

which does not make sense, if all I want is to have a variable `useOptionB` set true or false.
(unless, I have to make `useOptionB = not args.noOptionB` but it feels a bit wierd, doesn't it)

The alternative also does not make sense

```
import argparse
parser =  argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--useOptionC",help="activate the useOptionC option", action="store_false")
args=parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

so

```
python program.py
Namespace(useOptionC=True)

python program.py --useOptionC
Namespace(useOptionC=False)
```

in that case the default is to use the option C but the argument that says "Use" actually deactivates it.

It is a matter of semantics I suppose, but can someone write an example that makes sense of that option?

Comment: I usually use it with [`dest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#dest) parameter, which sets the name of target variable. Thus I would use `"--noOptionB",dest="useOptionB", action="store_false"`

Comment: `store_false` is just `store_const` with `default=True` and `const=False`.  To the program, if not the programmer, using `--foobar' makes as much sense anything else.

Comment: Contrary to the subject line, you are really puzzled about 'store_false'.  'store_true' is clear enough.  'store_true' is used much more than 'store_falce'.  Recent versions added a `argparse.BooleanOptionalAction` action class, which is similar to defining a pair of 'store_true' and 'store_false' with the same dest.

Answer (score 2):

Arguably `store_false` makes some sense when combined with `dest`, e.g.

```
...add_argument("--quiet", action="store_false", dest=info)
```

it gives a little bit more readable code:

```
if opts.info:
    print("Now doing this")
...
if opts.info:
    print("Now doing that")
```

(instead of `if not opts.quiet:` ...)

Comment: Ultimately the 'sense' the OP is trying to find comes from "reading' the words, whether it's the flag or dest.  By the way, the OP is using `argparse` not `optparse`. :)

Comment: @hpaulj I'm used to the term "options" (Linux background), but I'm using `argparse` as well. I corrected the typo (`add_xxx`), thanks for noticing me.

Answer (score -1):

use store_true will make sense.

```
import argparse
parser =  argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--useOptionC",help="activate the useOptionC option", action="store_true")
args=parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

Comment: This is a valid response to the subject line.  The question text puzzles over `store_false`.